# Yaml properties as a Map in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

We have a `spring-boot` project and are using `application.yml` files. This works exactly as described in the `spring-boot` documentation. `spring-boot` automatically looks in several locations for the files, and obeys any environment overrides we use for the location of those files.

Now we want to also expose those `yaml` properties as a Map. According to the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-yaml) this can be done with `YamlMapFactoryBean`. However `YamlMapFactoryBean` wants me to specify which `yaml` files to use via the `resources` property. I want it to use the same `yaml` files and processing hierarchy that it used when creating properties, so that I can take still take advantage of "magical" features such as placeholder resolution in property values.

I didn't see any documentation on if this was possible.
I was thinking of writing a MapFactoryBean that looked at the `environment` and simply reversed the "flattening" performed by the `YamlProcessor` when creating the `properties` representation of the file.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Hi Patrick, I have exactly similar problem. I'm wondering which solution you implemented and if you can share something as per your experience with loading yml as map.

Comment: @TheCodingFrog That specific project got cancelled before the work got prioritized. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ConfigFileApplicationContextListener` contains the logic for searching for files in various locations. And `PropertySourcesLoader` loads a file (`Resource`) into property sources. Neither is really designed for standalone use, but you could easily duplicate them if you want more control. The `PropertySourcesLoader` delegates to a collection of `PropertySourceLoaders` so you could add one of the latter that delegates to your `YamlMapFactoryBean`.

A slightly awkward but workable solution would be to use the existing machinery to collect the YAML on startup. Add a new `PropertySourceLoader` to your `META-INF/spring.factories` and let it create new property sources, then post process the `Environment` to extract the source map(s).

Beware, though: creating a single `Map` from multiple YAML files, or even a single one with multiple documents (let alone multiple files with multiple documents) isn't as easy as you might think. You have a map-merge problem, and someone is going to have to define the algorithm. The flattening done in `YamlMapPropertiesBean` and the merge in `YamlMapFactoryBean` are just two choices out of (probably) a larger set of possibilities.